# Disable a single storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Is there a simple way to disable a single storyboard scene based on a condition?

I'm using to check if location services are enabled for my app:

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied
```

If the above is true then I want to disable a scene that I created and the associated segues to get to that scene (I'm using left/right swipe gestures).

** UPDATED: I was confusing multiple storyboards with multiple scenes...my question has been updated to reflect this. I'm wanting to disable a specific scene in my storyboard, not a storyboard.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you have more than one storyboard, or are you just talking about disabling certain view controllers in your one storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar I have one view controller with 2 storyboards. I want to disable the second storyboard under the condition that location services have been disabled for the app.

Comment: In an app there is one storyboard that is automatically loaded when the app starts (which is normally MainStoryboard). If you have other storyboards, then you have to explicitly load them -- so just don't do that if you don't want it loaded. But I suspect that you are confusing terms -- I don't see how you can have 2 storyboards but only one view controller.

Comment: @rdelmar It's possible that I'm confusing terms. I'm a very part time developer. I used the GUI to create a second storyboard based on a left/right swipe gesture. I simply want to disable this second storyboard from ever being displayed based on whether or not location services are enabled for the app. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just put code in the gesture recognizer's handler to check the status of the location service's availability, and don't load the new storyboard if it's not turned on.

Comment: @rdelmar The gesture recognizer wasn't done programmatically, it was done through the GUI. How would I override that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18182/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-donavon-yelton)

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you should write an action in your view controller that uses the condition(s) you set to choose the scene to segue to (or none at all). Don't just have a button or gesture trigger a push segue -- have it trigger the action in the view controller so that you can select the next scene in your code.

It's all well and good that you can set up segues right in the storyboard file, and it makes a great demo, but when you want to determine the destination scene at runtime you need to do that in code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a hint from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309104/enable-disable-swiper-gesture-or-view-change-in-storyboard

I just created an IBOutlet in the header for a swipe gesture and placed the following code in an if statement that checks if the user has location services enabled or not and wired it up in addition to the segue in IB:

```
swipe.enable = NO;
```

Thanks for the assistance all!